# Rendering with VBO using JOGL trows exception at random

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vbo

I have been triing to write my rendering application with JOGL. But I am expiriencing an issue with VBO. Under linux it runs fine everytime, but under Windows it keeps crashing. I dont know what I am missing. I made my code for serving VBOs combining various tutorial, because there are very few for java and not speaking about JOGL.

I have read this:

http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25672.0
I modiefied my code, so I pass GL2 instance from init function of my class, which is derived from GLEventListener as function argument all the way to my VBOClass functions.
(I dont store GL2 instance as a class property)
But that didn't help

So my class:

```
public class VBOMesh {
private int vertexVBOId;
private int normalVBOId;
private int texCoordVBOId;

public VBOMesh(GL2 gl) {
    IntBuffer ib = IntBuffer.allocate(4);

    gl.glGenBuffers(4, ib);

    vertexVBOId = ib.get(0);
    normalVBOId = ib.get(1);
    texCoordVBOId = ib.get(2);
}

public void setVetices(GL2 gl, List<Vector3> vetices)
{
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBOId);
    gl.glBufferData( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vetices.size()*3*Float.SIZE, VectorListToFloatBuffer(vetices,3), GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void setTexCoords(GL2 gl, List<Vector3> texCoords)
{
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordVBOId);
    gl.glBufferData( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoords.size()*2*Float.SIZE, VectorListToFloatBuffer(texCoords,2), GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void setNormals( GL2 gl, List<Vector3> normals)
{
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalVBOId);
    gl.glBufferData( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals.size()*3*Float.SIZE, VectorListToFloatBuffer(normals,3), GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void Draw( GL2 gl, List<Integer> indices)
{      
    IntBuffer indiceBuffer = Buffers.newDirectIntBuffer( indices.size() );

    for (int ind : indices) {
        indiceBuffer.put(ind);
    }

    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalVBOId);
    gl.glNormalPointer( GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordVBOId);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBOId);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, indiceBuffer.capacity(), GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indiceBuffer.rewind());
    //gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_LINES, 0, 24);

    gl.glBindBuffer( GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GLPointerFunc.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}

private Buffer VectorListToFloatBuffer(List<Vector3> vectors, int floatsToTake)
{
    if(floatsToTake > 4)
    {
        throw new InvalidParameterException("floats to take greater than 4");
    }

    FloatBuffer buffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(vectors.size()*3);

    for (Vector3 vector : vectors) 
    {
        float [] arr = {0.f,0.f,0.f};

        if(vector != null)
        {
            arr = vector.getVector3AsGLArray();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < floatsToTake; i++) 
        {
            buffer.put(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return buffer.rewind();
}
```

}

The exception occurs at glBufferData.

I am out of ideas so I ask.

Comment: This is from the generated output file:


`#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x697c851e, pid=6476, tid=7160`

From stacktrace:
j  jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glBufferData(IJLjava/nio/Buffer;I)V+67
j  SceneTools.VBOMesh.setNormals(Ljavax/media/opengl/GL2;Ljava/util/List;)V+35

Comment: end if you debug step through it, do the parameters check out?

Comment: normalVBOId was like 3 or so, that looks correct, then buffer capacity is 942 for model I am testing on, which is 3 times size of list containing the vectors, so that look OK. But what i pass as a size to glBufferData is a large number due to Float.SIZE, I am not sure If it should be there or not.

Comment: Accusing JOGL instead of assuming that the problems probably comes from your code isn't very smart. If you had used direct NIO float buffers created with com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers, it would have worked from the very beginning everywhere. If you had read the documentation of the method, you would have found your mistake by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float.SIZE returns the number of *bits* in a single float (32) while you want the number of *bytes* in a float.

Replace each instance of `Float.SIZE` with `(Float.SIZE/Byte.SIZE)` or just `4`, or a self defined constant `BYTES_IN_FLOAT`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I belive, that those java VBO tutorials i have read missed this completely.